# Different ways to open Selector in java

Tags: java, selector

What is the difference between `SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector()` and `Selector.open()`?

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc of `Selector.open()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#open%28%29) states

> The new selector is created by invoking the `openSelector` method of the
>   system-wide default `java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider` object.

They are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are same.

```
public static Selector open() throws IOException {
        return SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
    }
```

above method used in Selector class.